# Quartz.NET, много задач и отслеживание ошибок

Tags: c#, .net-core, quartz

Суть: есть программа, которая обращается во множестве Quartz задачах к proxy, который запущен рядом с программой, но бывают ситуации такие, когда падает сам proxy или сайт, к которому обращается proxy.

Как отслеживать все ошибки обращения к proxy и управлять задачами, которые должны так же обратиться к этому proxy, т.е. их надо поставить на паузу на N секунд/минут, а потом возобновить снова, считая, что proxy/сайт уже встали обратно, но вопрос в том - как? Если задач, условно говоря, будет 100.000, одновременно будет исполняться больше 100 задач.

Пока была 1 идея: сделать сервис, в которой каждая задача будет давать репорт о неудаче обращения к proxy (или сайту), когда ошибок набирается, условно говоря, 10 штук за 1 секунду - останавливаем все остальные задачи на 1 минуту, но, допустим, первые 10 задач сразу зарепортили ошибки и не будут дальше ничего делать, а остальные 90 так и будут пробовать сделать запрос к proxy, как быть в этой ситуации?

Так же еще вопрос: как грамотно потом перезапустить задачи, которые уже пробовали сделать запрос на proxy, но ушли в ошибку?

Comment: Как одну задачу вы бы отслеживали, так же и 100.

Comment: @aepot с одной понятно, там конкретно для неё можно всё сделать, но смысл то в том, что неизвестно на сколько может упасть сайт, например, смысл мне делать 100 запросов сразу, когда на первом запросе от любой задачи можно это увидеть и остановить все остальные?

Comment: Quartz по-моему самостоятельно запускает джобы если они упали, если нет, то вроде бы должно быть свойство при конфигурировании джобы...

Comment: Ну если упало, подождать, перезапустить, если упало ещё раз, подождать подольше, перезапустить, и так далее.

Comment: @aepot логично, однако, я про это в вопросе и написал, вопрос в другом: как это грамотно сделать? Через сторонний сервис, который будет паузить все задачи в quartz или как-то по другому?

Comment: @OwDafuq зачем вам вообще париться с таким? В onExecute (или как там метод у джобы называется) просто проверяйте что прокси жив. Если сдох - `return` из джобы. Если будете руками пытаться перепланировать джобу - то может всё сломаться, но есть шедулеры из кварца которые вроде бы умеют в перепланирование

Comment: @Aarnihauta зачем париться - затем, что это основная задача программы - гонять данные именно через прокси и никак иначе, если сайт или прокси умерли - программа не работает и не должна делать никакие джобы какое-то время. С перепланирование разобрались уже, вроде бы, теперь только понять как отслеживать жизнь прокси и сайта, и реагировать на ошибки, чтобы можно было остановить все джобы на время

Comment: @OwDafuq странная задача. Зачем вырубать джобы если прокси умерло если можно просто поставить заглушку. Точно ли ТЗ прямо такое или вы урезали его для краткости вопроса? Ну если тогда прокси умерло, то можно Environment.Exit(0), но вот как обратно правильно запустить не скажу(( это уже наверное больше для девопсов задачка как обратно запустить

Comment: @Aarnihauta именно тз, потому что прокси шифрует трафик сертификатом (работы с гос. порталом, куда просто так не кинешь запрос), поэтому без него вообще никак и нужно ждать, пока оно встанет обратно. Выходить из программы не надо точно, потому что это будет еще и API, которое будет принимать запросы от пользователей, а дальше это идет в quartz задачу и выполняется в фоне

Comment: Паттерн Circuit Breaker.